# JAVA application with administrative privileges

Tags: java, cmd, network-programming, system, elevated-privileges

Is it possible to run a java application with administrative privileges.

So, the idea is to have these privileges and automate installations on the system by simple running a system check for already downloaded dependencies and then install the dependencies / softwares so as to reduce the DEV task.

Comment: Typically, the application will run with the same privileges as the user that launched the application.  So run the app as an administrator would be my first suggestion.

Comment: yes, but running as admin everytime is crazy....is there anyway to code it